# Why we get diffraction minimum at $\sin \theta = \frac{\lambda}{d} $

Tags: visible-light, diffraction

One of the possible explanation of this is:

> If we have a $2k$ rays and number them between $1$ and $2k$, $1$ ray will destruct $k$, because the additional distance of ray $k$ is $\frac{d}{2} \sin \theta$ and it makes it out of phase by $\pi$. Ray $2$ ray will
>   destruct $k+1$ ray and so on. That's why we've got a minimum.

[image]

And we've got a minimum when $$\sin \theta = \frac{\lambda}{d}$$
But I still do not understand, what happens to ray $2k$. Because the latest rays, which can destruct themselves are $k-1$ and $2k - 1$. So we leave ray $2k$ and it makes the spot not dark. Also working with $n$ light rays makes the explanation and formula doesn't work. Because we cant present odd number as $2k$ and we also can't find the middle ray, when we work with even count of rays.

Answer (score -1):

The counting should be done like this?

You just add $k$ to the designation of the first ray.

Ray $1$ will be exactly out of phase with ray $k+1$
Ray $2$ will be exactly out of phase with ray $k+2$
.
.
.
.
.
Ray $k-1$ will be exactly out of phase with ray $2k-1$
Ray $k$ will be exactly out of phase with ray $2k$

PS - If $k$ is very large then ray $2k$ will produce an insignificant effect on its own.

Comment: Ok, I think you mean something like on this [pic(link)](http://labman.phys.utk.edu/phys222core/modules/m9/images/Image3.gif), but I don't think it is correct, because the slit is splitted into it in an incorrect halves (one of them is 5 and the other one is 6 units length)

Comment: @G.Belyanin Do not worry as in the end one secondary source will not make very much difference.